# Swift regex find all

Tags: ios, regex, swift

I have a html part:
http://pastebin.com/FCcGNdwJ

And this is my regex:

```
<div class="cl_price">[\s\.\w<>="$\/]*Your Price\s*\$(\d+.\d+)|<div class="cl_price">[\s\.\w<>="$\/]*\$(\d+.\d+)
```

When i use Python, and run the following code:

```
results = re.findall(r'%s' % regex, text)
```

[findall python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall)

I got something like this:

```
[('', '59.00'), ('74.00', ''), ('', '69.95'), ('74.00', ''), ('', '39.99'), ('', '39.95'), ('', '79.95'), ('', '29.95'), ('', '129.99'), ('', '59.00'), ('', '35.00'), ('', '35.00'), ('19.00', ''), ('', '39.00'), ('18.00', ''), ('', '69.95'), ('', '79.00'), ('', '54.95'), ('74.99', ''), ('', '79.95'), ('', '35.00'), ('', '95.00'), ('15.00', ''), ('15.00', ''), ('74.00', ''), ('', '39.00'), ('', '39.00'), ('', '39.00'), ('', '129.00'), ('15.00', ''), ('', '34.95'), ('', '39.95'), ('', '9.95'), ('', '79.99'), ('', '59.95'), ('', '49.99'), ('74.00', ''), ('74.00', ''), ('', '35.00'), ('', '69.00')]
```

Then i tried to do the following in Swift. My last try was:

```
do {
            let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: regex, options: [])
            let nstext = value as NSString
            let all = NSRange(location: 0, length: nstext.length)
           let results = regex.matchesInString(value, options: [], range: all)



            return results.map { nstext.substringWithRange($0.range)}
        } catch {
            return []
        }
```

And it returns me:

```
["<div class=\"cl_price\">\n\n                        <div class=\"regular_price\">\n                  Regular Price $249.00"]
```

How can i do output like in Python ?

Comment: What do you WANT the output to be?

Comment: i want output like in python

Comment: @Arti Are you trying to parse HTML? Note that it's not possible to parse HTML using regular expressions since HTML is not a regular language. Why don't you use an HTML parser instead?

Comment: I can't do this, i should do this only with regex

Comment: You must do this only in regex? Why? Is this some kind of assignment? Are libraries like [AEXML](https://github.com/tadija/AEXML) not available?

Answer (score 0):

Regular Expressions are not generally a good idea when parsing XML/HTML.

With that said, look at https://regex101.com/r/yN4aR2/1. You may also want to throw the entire HTML source into that regex101 page and check that it matches what you want.

Note that this is formatted for readability. It is not intended to be copied straight across into [[swift]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift) or whatever regex language you are using it in.